# How to create a proper global or OS level keybinding in OSX

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, macos-sierra

Let's say I set command-z to something in `system preferences -> keyboard -> shortcuts`. Every application on the planet will override my keybinding and command-z will "undo" instead of whatever I set it to do in OSX.

This is just an example, I have no desire to use command-z for anything other than undo, but if I did, how would I go about it? I have a keybinding i have used for years and a new application I have started using redefines it or some nonsense and it is driving me insane because my fingers do it automatically at this point. Further, what is the point of setting *any* keybindings in system preferences if any app, or even browser extension, can come along at some point in the future and override any of them?

Comment: Perhaps the shortcut needs to be application-specific instead of for all applications? This would fix your problem with the new app specifically.

Answer (score 1):

You can override a keyboard shortcut in an Application by adding an Application Shortcut in System Preferences > Keyboard. For example, if you create a keyboard shortcut for a certain app for Undo, then the default shortcut (<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>) will not work — only the new keyboard shortcut.

[image: System Preferences > Keyboard]

[image: Textmate with custom Undo shortcut]

Comment: This is interesting! I have created an automator service that i am adding a keybind for. The application in question appears to be eating my keybinding. I am going to play around with this and see if i can get it to stop somehow

Comment: The strange thing is that it is a chrome extension that is eating the keybinding. Even if I set something like Undo to be my keybinding, this extension blocks it.. This is maddening! How does a chrome extension have god mode control over my entire system's keybindings?